# Перенос строчки

Tags: php, строки

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста. Допустим, пользователь создал ооочень длинное сообщение без пробелов, оно портит дизайн (т.к блок растягивается и вылазит за пределы экрана), как можно разбить такой текст, или переносить его, если там нету пробелов?

Пример:
Исходная строка: ААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААА

Строка, которая выводится пользователю:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Т.е ограничения, на кол-во символов в блоке <div>

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
css overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Тоже не помогло(

Comment: @Angus123, http://jsfiddle.net/GjGbg/. Если так не устраивает, делите строку на длинные части и ставьте после каждой \n. Или же просто обрезайте сообщение до определенной длинны

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте максимальную ширину div`у.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.